# PVP Covenant options?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What are the options in the game for PVP covenants and what would the pros and cons be?  I'm a member of the Brotherhood of Blood right now but find it lacking in a few key areas.

I see other covenants but most of the wiki's are very bare right now so if anyone has a solid grasp on what's what in the PVP world, I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the `Brotherhood of Blood` covenant...

---

`The Blue Sentinels` which invade the world of the guilty (BoB covenant). This covenant also has its own arena to duel in at the cost of `Tokens of Virtue`. That would be my only con.

`Dragon's Remenants` is a summon PvP. Where you leave summon signs to be summoned and duel.

`The Rat King` covenant which allows you to traverse the `Grave of Saints` & `Door of Pharros` and combat grey spirits, which are people who are not part of the covenant that enter the area when you are wearing the covenant's corresponding ring.

`Bell Keeper` covenant A.K.A. `Bell Bros` are similar to the `Rat King` covenant. The difference being that you are teleported as a dark spirit to one of the bell locations when a player trespasses in the territory.

With those final two mentioned covenants, you are defending something. `Rat King` is the bonfire and `Bell Keeper` is the lever to ring the bell.

---

As for pros and cons, that is entirely what you want from your PvP experience. `Bell Keepers` tend to **gank** a lot. `Rat King` is a 1v1 with NPCs at your disposal. Aside from that, it is very opinionated.

Hope that's what you're looking for! :D

Comment: If you're really hurting for pvp, kill every single NPC at the end of a playthrough. Since your infamy carries through you'll be almost constantly invaded by sentinels. I learned this the hard way, unfortunately. I couldnt reset my infamy either because I killed the guy who pardons you xD